# if don't have data in database it should be ADD button display else EDIT button without page reload button should be change

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Example starting company name is empty it should be ADD Button, After click the ADD button enter some data and click the save Now it should be change automatically EDIT button without page reload how to call in ajax success function please suggest me.

[image]

**script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {

            var form_data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_company_insert_update',
                data: form_data,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $('#ccity').text($("#city").val());                               
                },
                error: function ()
                {
                     alert('failed');
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });

</script>
```

**form**

**below add and edit button how to call in ajax sucess**

```
<?php if (empty($s_city[0]) || empty($s_city)) {?>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7">
        <div class="profile-edit col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4">Add</div>
    </a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
    </a>                                          
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: in which form you are getting the data from the controller? like data.city=='some_city' ??

Comment: Note: After the e.preventDefault(); your missing `}` should be `});`

Comment: same form only getting data form conroller shalll i put full code..
My requirement is if don't have data in database it should be ADD button else EDIT button without page reload button should be change please refer images @adeel

Comment: My requirement is if don't have data in database it should be ADD button else EDIT button without page reload button should be change how to call the php code in ajax success function @wolfgang1983

Comment: but you have to check the database once that the value is store. ajax call will do this with out  page load. you can simply have the jquery magic. just like `('#add_div_id').hide`

Comment: empty means  edit should be hide add button should be appear..data exist means edit should be appear and add should be hide without page reload...this is my requirement

Comment: If you still cant find solution for this issue. come to chat ill explain https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146504/codeigniter

Comment: sir minimum 20 reputation required to chat online...@FairyDancer

Comment: what you ended with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your form like as follow

```
<form action="" id="data_form" method="post" > 
        <div class="dashboard-column-main"> 
            <div class="dashboard-container"> 
                <div class="title-section"> 
                    <h3 class="section_title">Company Information</h3> 
                </div> 

                <div class="profile-back"> 
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion"> 
                        <div class="panel panel-default"> 

                            <div class="panel-heading row" id="first"> 
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Company Name</div> 
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis" id="cname"><?php 
                                    if (isset($s_company_name)) { 
                                    echo $s_company_name; 
                                } 
                                ?> 
                            </div> 

                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> 
                                <div class="profile-edit col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 aj-text"> 
                                    <?php if (empty($s_company_name[0]) || empty($s_company_name)): ?> 
                                        Add 
                                    <?php else: ?> 
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit 
                                    <?php endif; ?> 
                                </div> 
                            </a> 
                        </div> 


                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse"> 
                            <div class="panel-body"> 
                                <div class="row"> 
                                    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-2 text-center"> 
                                        <label class="col-md-4">Company Name</label> 
                                        <div class="col-md-8"> 
                                            <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" class="form-control" 
                                            value="<?=(isset($s_company_name))?$s_company_name:null; ?>"/><br> 
                                            <input type="hidden" name="save_type" id="save_type" value="<?=(empty($s_company_name[0]) || empty($s_company_name)) ? 'Save' : 'Update'; ?>"> 

                                            <?php if (empty($s_company_name[0]) || empty($s_company_name)): ?> 
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btn" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse">Save</button> 
                                            <?php else: ?> 
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btn" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse">Update</button> 
                                            <?php endif; ?> 
                                            <button type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button> 
                                        </div> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

And your script will have to like this

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () { 

        $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_company_insert_update', 
                data: form_data, 
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) 
                { 
                    $(".aj-text").html(result.replace_text); 
                    $(".aj-text-btn").html(result.btn_text); 
                    $("#save_type").val(result.save_type);
                    $('#cname').text($("#company_name").val()); 
                }, 
                error: function () 
                { 
                    alert('failed'); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

And replace your controller supplier_company_insert_update function as follow

```
public function supplier_company_insert_update() { 

    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('supplier_otherdetails'); 
    $this->db->where('supplierid_fk', $this->session->id); 
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $save_type = $this->input->post('save_type');
    $company_name = $this->input->post('company_name');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
        $this->Profile_model->update_supplier_company(); 
        //redirect('welcome/suppliercompany'); 
    } else { 
        $this->Profile_model->insert_supplier_company(); 
        //redirect('welcome/suppliercompany'); 
    } 

    if(trim($company_name)!='')
        echo json_encode(array('replace_text' => 'Edit', 'btn_text' => 'Update', 'save_type' => $save_type)); 
    else
        echo json_encode(array('replace_text' => 'Save', 'btn_text' => 'Save', 'save_type' => $save_type)); 
}
```

Hope this will work for you. If is there any help let us know...